# normal vector to surface $z=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: geometry

I have a surface defined as $z=\frac{-1}{r}$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and I'd like to know how to calculate a surface normal vector at a point $(x,y)$.

An approximation would be acceptable.

Comment: The [normal vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_normal) of a surface implicitly defined by $F(x,y,z)=C$ (i.e. a level sets of $F$) is $\nabla F(a)$ at the point $x=a$. Your surface is $z+(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}=0$...

Comment: Ok, but how do I work out $\nabla F(a)$? Sorry, my maths is very rusty...

Comment: Is it $\nabla F(a)=(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\frac{\partial F}{\partial z})$?

Comment: Richard: Yes, that's the gradient of $F$. And here $F$ is..?

Comment: @anon: um, $z+(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}=0$, but it may take me several days to differentiate it... :)

Comment: Now, now. I know you can differentiate it, just take your time. :)

Comment: I'm getting something like $(x^{-2},y^{-2},1)$...

Comment: Nope. Use the chain rule: $f(g)=g^{-1/2}$ and $g(x)=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Brain and laptop both about to run out of batteries... thanks for your help anon - I'll have to try to work out the rest tomorrow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1411/discussion-between-richard-inglis-and-anon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We went over the answer in chat. To review, in order to differentiate $(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}$ we used the chain rule after setting $g(x)=x^2+y^2$ and $f(g)=g^{-1/2}$, so that $f'(g)=-(1/2)g^{-3/2}$ and $g_x=2x$ (similarly for $d/dy$) so the gradient (and therefore the normal vector, though not the *unit* normal) can be expressed as
$$\nabla(z+(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2})=\left(\frac{-x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}},\frac{-y}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}},1\right).$$